# How to remove hoax subtitles from mp4 files by ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

Sometimes I get some mp4 files which include a stream of type data. When I play such files by vlc I see an additional subtitle which is not really a subtitle stream. For example it just includes "Chapter 03"! Indeed the original mp4 file should include a video and an audio stream, while ffmpeg shows an additional data stream. This is the same stream vlc shows as an additional subtitle stream. Sometimes the file includes four streams, a video, an audio and a real subtitle stream. I don't want to use -sn to remove this real subtitle. I just want to remove what to claim to be a subtitle stream and it's not. They're usually introduced to be a data stream, but vlc shows them as subtitle stream. I also don't want to use -dn or -map_metadata -1 to remove data from mp4, because sometimes the mp4 includes chapters data which I don't want to be removed. I just want to remove these hoax subtitles which are introduced as data.

How it's possible to be done by ffmpeg?

Comment: Please provide output from ffprobe -I yourfile.mp4.
That way at least we can see what's the issue I'll get back to you when I can.
Rgds

Comment: Ok, I pasted the output here: https://pastebin.com/QEY0GCCD
I tried to update the question and append this output to it, but it resulted in an scrambled text. So I decided to paste it there.